# YouTube videos reload when I replay them?

Tags: youtube

When you start a video, there is a light grey bar which indicates the loading of the video. How come when I replay the video (by clicking the 'replay' button or by clicking somewhere random on the horizontal play line), the video will load/buffer again?

It never used to be like this, but recently I've noticed that for some videos, this problem occurs.

I tried on both Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7.